# Is my code correct for an issue involving prime number tracking and consecutive addition?

Tags: python, primes

The question: Assume the availability of a function is_prime. Assume a variable n has been associated with positive integer. Write the statements needed to find out how many prime numbers (starting with 2 and going in increasing order with successively higher primes [2,3,5,7,11,13,...]) can be added before exceeding n. Associate this number with the variable k.

The code:

```
def is_prime():
    i = 2
    k = 0
    Again = True
    while Again = True:
        if total > n:
            Again = False
        for x in range(2,n):
            if x % i == 0:
                total = total
                k = k
                i += 1
            else:
                total += x
                k += 1
    return k
```

Comment: Homework? Maybe your class mates can help...

Comment: You should explain what your code is trying to do, as it is not clear. 1. You're supposed to assume that `is_prime` is available to use, not implement it yourself. 2. You're while loop control is rather eccentric. It should be something like `while total <= n:`, but I don't know where you're getting `n`.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct for an issue involving prime number tracking and consecutive addition.  Nor anything else.  The obvious issue is that it doesn't run, so it can't be correct.  One syntax bug is this:

```
while Again = True:
```

which should be:

```
while Again == True:
```

Another is that `total` is never initialized before it's value is used:

```
total += x
```

Once we fix those problems, your code still doesn't appear to work.  But let's back up a bit.  The stated problem says,

> Assume the availability of a function is_prime.

But you didn't do that -- you wrote your solution with the name `is_prime()`.  We should expect that there is a function named `is_prime(n)` and it tests if `n` is prime or not, returning `True` or `False`.  You are either given this, need to find one, write one, or simply assume it exists but never actually test your code.  But once you have this function, and it works, you shouldn't change it!

Here's my example `is_prime(n)` function:

```
def is_prime(n):
    """ Assume the availability of a function is_prime. """

    if n < 2:
        return False

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2

    for m in range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
        if n % m == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Now write your solution calling this function, but not changing this function.  Here's one possible algorithm:

- Write a function called `primes_in_sum(n)`
- Set the variable `prime` to 2 and the variable `k` (our counter) to
  0.
- Subtract `prime` from `n`.
- While `n >= 0`, increment `k`, and compute the next value of `prime`
  by keep adding one to `prime` until `is_prime(prime)` returns true.
  Then again subtract `prime` from `n`.  Back to the top of this loop.
- When the `while` condition fails, return `k`.

Test your code works by outputting some values:

```
for n in range(2, 100):
    # Assume a variable n has been associated with a positive integer
    print(n, primes_in_sum(n))
```

Check in your head that the results are reasonable.